# Segmentation fault with OR-Tools 9.8 Python on Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: python, or-tools

I donwloaded the bin packing problem code in python (you can find the code here: https://developers.google.com/optimization/pack/bin_packing) and tried to run it.
I've correctly installed ortools.
However when I try to run the program, it keeps me saying "Segmentation fault: 11".

> python3 bpp.py
> Segmentation fault: 11

I tried to uninstall and reinstall the module, I also created a new virtual environment installing only ortools dependencies in it, but the problem still.

How can I solve this?
Thanks

Additional information:

> python3 --version
> Python 3.12.1

> pip3 show ortools
> Name: ortools Version: 9.8.3296 Summary: Google
> OR-Tools python libraries and modules Home-page:
> developers.google.com/optimization Author: Google LLC Author-email:
> or-tools@google.com License: Apache 2.0

OS Big Sur version 11.7.10

Comment: Can you show how how to reproduce the problem, plus the *exact* output you're getting? Also relevant: Python version, OS version.

Comment: I run the program in the terminal: python3 bpp.py
Segmentation fault: 11 
     
     python3 --version
Python 3.12.1

     pip3 show ortools
Name: ortools
Version: 9.8.3296
Summary: Google OR-Tools python libraries and modules
Home-page: https://developers.google.com/optimization/
Author: Google LLC
Author-email: or-tools@google.com
License: Apache 2.0 
     
     OS Big Sur version 11.7.10

Comment: Add all relevant details **to the question** by editing it.

Comment: Does the program starts ? Is it in the loader ? Can you check the mac architecture and the python architecture ?